# How to push Notification when data changes in rest API in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, rest

Hi I'm creating a Rider app I want to push a Notification and show alert dialog to Rider when a Delivery Request is placed for him in Rest API, Delivery Request is coming from Rest API but I'm unable to show Notification to Rider . If any one have done this before or have any Idea please Guide.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following code:

```
http.post(
'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
 headers: <String, String>{
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': 'key=$serverToken',
 },
 body: jsonEncode(
 <String, dynamic>{
   'notification': <String, dynamic>{
     'body': 'this is a body',
     'title': 'this is a title'
   },
   'priority': 'high',
   'data': <String, dynamic>{
     'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
     'id': '1',
     'status': 'done'
   },
   'to': deviceToken,
 },
),
);
```

you can find server token in your firebase console->Project settings->Cloud messaging tab->server key

and device token is found after installing `firebase_messaging:` package and

```
FirebaseMessaging fcm=FirebaseMessaging();
print(fcm.getToken());//deviceToken
```

Comment: I'm not using Firebase , how can I achieve this only using Rest API.